# Is there a javascript function to open a file input window in a specific directory on the local computer?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to access a file on the local computer given a path.

One method I was considering is if it was possible to navigate to the directory in a file picker window and prompt the user to select the file.

Is there any functionality that would allow this?

Thanks.

Comment: You really have zero control over that.

Comment: It's impossible in browser & totally doable in e.g. [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/)-like environment.

Comment: The only way to have the browser open a file selection window is clicking on `<input type="file">` but the folder is either the one from last time or some default like Documents. However it is possible that this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/); you should tell us what this file is / does and what your goal is here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.